# when clicking on the routerLink angular throws ASSERTION ERROR

Tags: angular, routerlink, angular-routerlink

This is my first angular 8 application, and now when I am trying to setup routerlinks and when I click on the links I get from the google console the error:
Error: ASSERTION ERROR: Provided Component class doesn't contain Component definition. Please check whether provided class has @Component decorator. [Expected=> null != null <=Actual].
On compilation there is no error and I can not find any solution to the problem with the help of professor Google.

The app.module.ts file looks like this:
`

```
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
  import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
  import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
  import { ProductList, ProductListComponent } from './product/product-list.component'
  import { Comment } from '@angular/compiler';
  import { ConvertToSpacesPipe } from './shared/convert-to-spaces.pipe';
  import { starComponent } from './shared/star.component';
  import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
  import { ProductDetailComponent } from './product/product-detail.component'
  import { WelcomeComponent } from './home/welcome.component';
  import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

  @NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      ProductList,
      ConvertToSpacesPipe,
      starComponent,
      ProductDetailComponent,
      WelcomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      RouterModule.forRoot([
        {path: 'products', component: ProductListComponent},
        {path: 'products/:id', component: ProductDetailComponent},
        {path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent},
        {path: '', redirectTo: '/welcome', pathMatch: 'full'},
        {path: '**', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full'}
      ])
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    exports: [
      RouterModule,
    ],
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

`

product-list.component.ts looks like this:
`

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { IProduct } from "./product";
import { ConvertToSpacesPipe } from "../shared/convert-to-spaces.pipe";
import { ProductService } from "./product.service";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";

@Component({
    templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
  })
export class ProductList implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {

  }
    pageTitle: string = 'Product list Rating';
    imageWidth: number = 50;
    imageMargin: number = 2;
    showImage: boolean = true;
    errormsg: string = `err`;
    sub!: Subscription;
    private _listFilter : string = '' ;
    get listFilter(): string {
      return this._listFilter;
    }
    set listFilter(value: string) {
      this._listFilter = value;
      this.filteredProducts = this.preformFilter(value);
    }
    filteredProducts: IProduct[] = [];
    products: IProduct[] = [];
    toggleImage(): void {
        this.showImage = !this.showImage;
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.sub = this.productService.getProducts().subscribe({
        next: products => {
          this.products = products;
          this.filteredProducts = this.products;
        },
        error: err => this.errormsg = err,

      });
      
      this.listFilter = '';
      this.startup();
    }
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }
    startup(): void {
      if (this.showImage) {
        console.log('tråd'); 
      }
      if (!this.showImage) {
        console.log('Show Image')
      }
    }
    preformFilter(filteredBy : string): IProduct[] {
      filteredBy = filteredBy.toLocaleLowerCase();
      return this.products.filter((product: IProduct) => 
      product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(filteredBy));
    }
    onRatingClicked(message : string): void {
      this.pageTitle = 'Product list Rating ' + message;
    }   
};
export class ProductListComponent {
  onNotify(messeges : string ): void {
    console.log('shit')
  }
};
```

`My app.component.ts looks like this:`

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'pm-root',
  template: `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand">{{pageTitle}}</a>
    <ul class='nav nav-pills'>
      <li><a class="nav-link" routerLink='/welcome' routerLinkActive="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" routerLink='/products' routerLinkActive="active">Product list</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  pageTitle: string = 'Acme Project Mangement';
}
```

`the welcome.component.ts looks like this:`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './welcome.component.html'
})
export class WelcomeComponent {
  public pageTitle = 'Welcome';
}
```

`

Please help me find a solution to this problem, my future is dependent on me learning angular, so fixing this problem would mean a lot.

Comment: ProductListComponent doesn't have @Component decorator.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such component called "ProductListComponent" in your code. Use the name "ProductList" instead of "ProductListComponent" in the router. Hope that will resolve the issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes there is…..

Comment: @AndrewAllen I am not sure. At least not in the question except in the import. If it is there, then it has to be there in the "declarations" as well.